# Multiple linked jQuery UI datepickers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to be able to link multiple pairs of jQuery UI datepicker instances so that the second one in each pair can't select a date earlier than the first. I'm following [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range) to get started.

Example:

```
<ul>
<li>
<input class="counter" name="counter" type="hidden" value="43"/>
<label>Start: </label><input name="start_43" id="start_43" size="10" />
<label>End: </label><input name="end_43" id="end_43" size="10" />
</li>

<li>
<input class="counter" name="counter" type="hidden" value="44"/>
<label>Start: </label><input name="start_44" id="start_44" size="10" />
<label>End: </label><input name="end_44" id="end_44" size="10" />
</li>
</ul>
```

I'm looping over the instances by finding the "counter" number:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var starts = $("input[name='counter']");
    var dates = new Array();
    starts.each(function(){
        var x = this.value;
        // http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range
        dates[x] = $( "#start_"+x+", #end_"+x ).datepicker({
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "#start_"+x ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" );
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat ||
            $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
            selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates[x].not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This works to enable a datepicker on each input but it doesn't prevent the second instance from choosing a date before the first. In fact it *requires* that the second instance choose a date before the first. When selected, the second instance populates both inputs!

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% about what the parseDate is for, or why you're retrieving the instance from the datastore.  However, I believe your primary problem is the this.id test. IDs never start with # in the actual DOM element.

```
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var option = this.id.indexOf("start_") != -1 ? "minDate" : "maxDate";
    dates[i].not(this).datepicker("option", option, selectedDate);
}
```

The above should do it, or you could just take the hash out of your code probably (which I just did and seems to work fine). :]

Comment: @oleonard Just to be clear, all you have to do is change the following line, removing the hash in front of the word start: var option = this.id == "start_"+x ? "minDate" : "maxDate"

Comment: Ah, you're exactly right! I didn't realize that "#" had snuck in. Now it works correctly. Thanks for the extra set of eyes!

Comment: @oleonard I know exactly what you mean. My team lead was staring at something for about a half hour when I suggested he should really let me see if a second head might help reveal the problem. "I don't see a scope for this variable. Did you forget to type 's dot'?" Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$("#FirstCal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M d, yy',
        navigationAsDateFormat: true, prevText: 'M', nextText: 'M',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "both",
        showStatus: true,
        firstDay: 0,
        changeFirstDay: false,
        beforeShow: customRange,
        buttonImage: '/Content/images/Calendar_img.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });

    $("#secondCal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M d, yy',
        navigationAsDateFormat: true, prevText: 'M', nextText: 'M',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "both",
        showStatus: true,
        firstDay: 0,
        changeFirstDay: false,
        beforeShow: customRange,
        buttonImage: '/Content/images/Calendar_img.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });

function customRange(input) {
    var min = new Date();
    var min = new Date('<%=DateTime.Now.Year %>', '0', '1');
    var max = new Date('<%=DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year %>', '11', '31');

    var dateMin = min;
    var dateMax = max;

    if (input.id == "firstCal" && $("#secondCal").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
        if (dateMin < min) {
            dateMin = min;
        }
    }
    else if (input.id == "secondCal") {
        if ($("#firstCal").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
            dateMin = $("#firstCal").datepicker("getDate");
        }
    }
    return {
        minDate: dateMin,
        maxDate: dateMax
    };
}
```